# LM348 replacable by LM358

Tags: operational-amplifier, surface-mount, function-generator

I want to give SMD soldering a try and therefore I was looking for some useful circuit (no LED-blink-crap) I could build more or less easily. So I found a nice DIY function generator [here](http://www.circuitspecialists.com/kit-23.html). It uses originally an LM348 OpAmp, which is not in stock at my local electronics store and in general not as SO-8. I wondered if I could simply use two LM358, that are easy to get. Unfortunately I have no clue about OpAmps and so I hope somebody can tell me if this is a compatible replacement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should work more-or-less. The LM348 is kind of a quad \$\mu A741\$, so it has a class AB output stage.

[image]

The LM358/LM324 has a different kind of output stage that is more prone to crossover distortion. You might want to use a pullup resistor of 5 or 10K from the sine and triangle outputs to +9V to help reduce crossover distortion (by forcing it into Class A).

[image]

You could also use a [4558](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/rc4558.pdf), which is more common and thus may be more easily available to you.

[image]

Using an op-amp as a comparator, as they are doing (looks like one of the late Peter Crowcroft's circuits?) is not the best- slew rates will make the square waves less square, but that's kind of inherent in the current design.

Comment: Brilliant!
Has the RC4558 any advantages towards the LM358? Could I omit the pullup with those?

Comment: BtW, I think it already has a 2K pullup via R7 and R8. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, there's no need for the pullup. It is essentially the same as the 348 for your purposes.

Comment: I finally had some free time and succeeded with building this little board. The RC4558 works like charm!